# Smart Home modes trait not show in UI

Tags: actions-on-google

I add the Modes trait and some settings to my device, but the UI doesn't show any option. Also I have tried with Toogle trait and it doesn't show it either.
(I have my assistant in Spanish, and when I select the supported language in the SYNC, I specified 'es' tag).

This is my SYNC response:

```
{
   "requestId":"8280087254750701149",
   "payload":{
       "agentUserId":2,
       "devices":[{
            "id":"34",
            "type":"action.devices.types.OUTLET",
            "traits":["action.devices.traits.OnOff","action.devices.traits.Modes"],
            "attributes":{
                  "availableModes":[{
                       "name":"auxiliar",
                       "name_values":[{
                            "name_synonym":["auxiliar"],
                            "lang":"es"
                        }],
                        "settings":[{
                            "setting_name":"encendido",
                            "setting_values":[{
                                 "setting_synonym":["encendido"],
                                 "lang":"es"
                            }]
                        },
                        {
                            "setting_name":"apagado",
                            "setting_values":[{
                                 "setting_synonym":["apagado"],
                                 "lang":"es"
                            }]
                        },
                        {
                            "setting_name":"suspendido",
                            "setting_values":[{
                                 "setting_synonym":["suspendido"],
                                 "lang":"es"
                            }]
                        }],
                        "ordered":true
                  }]
            },
            "name":{
                 "defaultNames":["EVVC200000091"],
                 "name":"Cargador laboratorio",
                 "nicknames":["cargador_labo"]
            },
            "willReportState":true,
            "deviceInfo":{
                 "manufacturer":"Orbis",
                 "swVersion":"00.01.31"
            },
            "customData":{
                 "serial":"EVVC200000091",
                 "fooValue":74,
                 "barValue":true,
                 "bazValue":"foo"
            }
       }]
   }
}
```

This is my QUERY response:

```
{"requestId":"15972376619501000208","payload":{"devices":{"34":{"currentModeSettings":{"auxiliar":"encendido"},"on":true}}}}
```

And the UI not show any option:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYuaT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every device trait is supported on every surface with touch controls. You should look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/touch-controls) for touch controls. Note that Modes and Toggles are not on the list for supported traits.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! And do you know if is posible to ask to the assistant for some custom values? Like for example, the charge in watts/hour of a charger. (I have seen a EnergyStorage trait, but it doesn't work correctly in spanish)

Comment: For the infinite space of custom values, you'd want to use a conversational action. Within the space of device-related values, there's likely a trait already or one should be created. With regards to EnergyStorage not working in Spanish, that seems to be unintentional.